# Ansible - How to launch(purchase) a reserved EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

How can I launch(purchase) a reserved EC2 instance using Ansible with EC2 module? I've googled using words something like 'ec2 reserved instance ansible' but no joy.

Or should I use AWS CLI instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the [Cloud module list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html) and found there isn't any modules out of the box that supports reserved instance - I think you try building a wrapper over the `AWS CLI` or `Python Boto SDK` [ or any SDK ].

This is the pseudo code for the playbook :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: 'Calling Python Code to reserve instance' 
      raw: python reserve-ec2-instance.py args
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create [Ansible module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html).
Also there are already created modules that you can use as examples [ansible-modules-extras/cloud/amazon](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/tree/devel/cloud/amazon).

PS:

> Modules can be written in any language and are found in the path
>   specified by ANSIBLE_LIBRARY or the --module-path command line option.
>
> By default, everything that ships with ansible is pulled from its
>   source tree, but additional paths can be added.
>
> The directory ”./library”, alongside your top level playbooks, is also
>   automatically added as a search directory.

Answer (score 2):

I just made a [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/2205) which might help you.

You could use it as follows:

```yaml
- name: Purchase reserved instances
  boto3:
    name: ec2
    region: us-east-1
    operation: purchase_reserved_instances_offering
    parameters:
      ReservedInstancesOfferingId: 9a06095a-bdc6-47fe-a94a-2a382f016040
      InstanceCount: 3
      LimitPrice:
        Amount: 123.0
        CurrencyCode: USD
  register: result

- debug: var=result
```

If you're interrested by this feature, feel free to vote up on the PR. :)